# Version list not displayed after pushing next version of ruby gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I have created a Ruby gem and pushed in rubygem org (version 1.0.0)

then i did some changes and again i pushed the next version (version 2.0.0)

After that,
 I opened the gem home page, the previous versions list is not displayed only the recent version number is displayed.

Ruby dependency, runtime dependency all are displayed
but Version is not enabled

Also dono how to add source code link,

my gemspec file as

```
Gem::Specification.new do |s|
  s.name        = 'xxx'
  s.version     = xxx::VERSION
  s.date        = '2014-04-28'
  s.summary     = "Hola!"
  s.description = "A simple hello world gem"
  s.authors     = ["xxxxx"]
  s.email       = 'xxxxx@gmail.com'
  s.files       = ["lib/xxx.rb"]
  s.homepage    =
    'https://github.com/xxx/xxx.git'
  s.license       = 'MIT'

  s.add_runtime_dependency 'rails', ['>= 3', '< 5']

  s.add_development_dependency 'rspec-rails', '2.13.0'

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed the version in the version.rb file? You need to specify the current version using the VERSION constant in the file **lib/{gem_name}/version.rb** like this:

```
module GemName
  VERSION = "2.0.0"
end
```

The version.rb file is loaded by the Gem Specification file to specify the version for the gem specification. Before releasing a new version of the gem the version number needs to be changed.This tells Rubygems about the new version.

Comment: i have added those file, from there only the version number is updating..  is there any other problem